# console/command prompt app .net/c#

Tags: c#, parsing, command-line, cmd

Any starting point/ideas for a custom console app which mimics the dos command prompt ?
Basically looking for best practices and ideas for where to start 
Perhaps using powershell which frankly i've not looked at yet !

I know this is a little retro but i've found some limitations in the web app done using asp.net mvc etc. ( few of them such as permission issues reading network files etc. and other downstream issues from there )

essentially i'd like to make this a pluggable app where this app will be able to load different list of commands to be executed

ideally, this would support *hyperlinks* too where clicking on a hyperlink would execute the related command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a project you might be interested in: [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several home-brewed command prompt controls; [here's one on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/commandprompt.aspx).

Otherwise you might try to [pass values and retrieve response from Command Prompt](http://www.geekpedia.com/code42_Pass-values-and-retrieve-response-from-Command-Prompt.html)